# Undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass for show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot seem to find the problem. In my venues `show` template, I want to show the venue name, and under that, I list all the venues in the database

```
<%= venu.name %>
<% @venus.each do |v| %>
```

I get the error that `@venus` is `nil`... but it is defined in my controller:

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

**venues_controller.rb**

```
 class VenuesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_venue, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      def index
          @venus = Venue.all
      end

      def show
         render :layout => nil
         @venus = Venue.all
      end

      def new
          @venu = Venue.new
      end

      def create
          @venu = Venue.new(venue_params)
          @venu.save
      end

      def edit
      end

      def update
      end

      def destroy
      end

      private

      def venue_params
          params.require(:venue).permit(:name, :phone, :address, :description, :type)
      end

      def find_venue
          @venu = Venue.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

I have a `resources :venues` route in my `routes.rb`.

I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `show` method, you should render at the end

```
def show
  @venus = Venue.all
  render :layout => nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `render :layout => nil` from your `show` action.

And in your view, you need to use the instance variable `@venu` instead of `venu`

```
<%= @venu.name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you use two instance variables for action `show`

`@venu` (via `find_venue` `before_filter`) & `@venus` via the action itself.

Best practice would be removing this line from action `show`, since `show` action normally used to show details for one element from a list.

```
@venus = Venue.all
```

and use `@venu` set by the `before_filter` instead.

---

But if you do want to keep both then re-order the lines in `show` action

```
@venus = Venue.all
render :layout => nil
```

Also, change the `venu` to `@venu` in the `show.html.erb` and if you like correct the typo in the instance variables `@venu` => `@venue` :) (Could happen to any of us)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in the `index` method, it should show all the `venus`, and in the `show` method it would show detailed view of each `venue`.

Try setting something like this:

```
def index
 @venus = Venue.all
end

def show
 render :layout => nil
 @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
end
```

now in `show.html.erb` you should be able to use

```
@venue.name
```

and in your `index.html.erb`, you can iterate over the venus like so:

```
<% @venus.each do |v| %>
 <%= link_to v do %>
  <%= v.name %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct. You can use `@venus = Venue.all` in your show view but because you render first it throws you an error. Just render at the end.